# Upgrading project to Angular 7 has broken Octopus deployment

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular7, octopus-deploy

### Background

- Angular 4.3 project
- Built using Jenkins
- "octo.exe pack ..." step to package output into nuget package
- Octopus to deploy to IIS

### Problem

Once the project is upgraded to Angular 7 the deploy step is erroring with this:

```
No files were found that match the substitution target pattern 'main*.bundle.js'
```

Since Angular 6 they renamed the files so that they no longer contained the "bundle" part.
I can't figure out where this is failing. Or where this substitution is defined. Anyone got any ideas?

Only things I've tried so far is using latest angular CLI version (7.1.0) to do the build (was previously webpack@3.9.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly found it minutes after posting the question.
In the Octopus Deploy process, for the step that was failing, there was "Features" -> "Substitute variables in files", and that had main*.bundle.js

Changing that to main*.js sorted it.

Hope this helps anyone else who comes across similar issue.